# How did Caprica Sharon know so much?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

During season one and early season two, the Caprica-based Cylon Model 8, Sharon "Athena" Agathon, is seen to have knowledge of the Sharon "Boomer" Valerii on Galactica. She hadn't been killed / resurrected, so how does she know Helo and remember meeting Starbuck ("I remember the first day I met you Starbuck, you were puking your guts out in the head because you'd eaten bad [something]")?

I've seen the entire series, so no need for spoiler alert.

How does this 8 know this information? Was it explained in the series?

Comment: Do you mean the Caprica based 8? It's been awhile since I've watched BSG, but I don't remember a plot line with 8 on Kobol like that.

Comment: D'OH!  Yep. That story was happening during the Kobol story-line. Got me wires crossed. Appy Polly Loggies,

Comment: The series does not ever address the mechanism used to transfer information between the two copies of Eight.

Answer (score 4):

I think this was mentioned in the series very vaguely. I don't remember the exact season/episode but when Helo asked Athena how could that be possible, she said something like same models shared same memories and this is how they recognise each other when they see themselves (or each other) in a crowded place (full of cylons).

A similar version of this happened between Dr. Gaius Baltar and another Model 6 who was captured in Battlestar Pegasus. She had memories but she was not in love with Baltar.

### To avoid the confusion, every cylon is different in their own lives and memories but they somehow share these knowledge. *It's like they can download the related memories when they need them, from a cloud.*

**EDIT:** *About Athena-Tyrol scene in Season 2 - Episode 6 - Part 2*

> The pregnant Sharon Valerii again shows that she has the memories of
>   the 'original' Boomer, which was previously shown in the season opener
>   when she started to tell Starbuck of the time they met. She also
>   displays this in "Home, Part II" where she tells Tyrol she has some of
>   Boomer's memories of him and in "Scar" where she displays some of
>   Boomer's memories of Starbuck to the other's obvious discomfort. - [Source](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Resurrection_Ship,_Part_II)

*About Athena-Helo (CAN'T REMEMBER WHICH EPISODE)*

> Sharon is able to impersonate Lieutenant Valerii convincingly, since
>   she has accessed Valerii's memories at least up until the point of
>   Helo being left behind on Caprica (TRS: "Flesh and Bone", "Scattered",
>   "Home, Part II", "Flight of the Phoenix", "Scar"). - [Source](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Sharon_Agathon#Cylon_cross-breeding_experiment_on_Caprica)

Comment: This would be a good answer if you could cite the episode. As it stands, it sounds like a *possible* thing that happened or just speculation. Also, they look exactly the same, why wold they need any shared memories to recognize each other?

Comment: @MeatTrademark I think s2xe6 called "Home", part 2 has a Sharon-Tyrol moment to support that. Also, when cylons try to rebuild Caprica to live in it, every cylon recognises Caprica 6 who caused Baltar to leak defense security codes of the entire planet. They behave like she is a hero. As you said, they look exactly the same. There must be reason why they can tell the difference from one to another. There are multiple examples in the series. I can only remember the 2 of them. Here is a link for that (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_(Battlestar_Galactica))

Comment: If you find the relevant passage as to how Sharon "Athena" Agathon has knowledge of the Sharon "Boomer" Valerii model, please edit it into your answer. I don't have access to my collection right now to rewatch and verify. So if you can, or someone else can, I'll upvote and accept (if it's good info). The stuff about Caprica 6 is interesting, but offtopic for this specific question. I'm only asking about "Boomer"/"Athena" and Cylons accessing memories w/out death *as explained in the show* (not online).

Comment: In this case there aren't any answers I can give as an official answer. There are multiple cases. In one case, Athena says to Tyrol that she *remembers* (this is tricky if you ask me) which I shared a link in my previous comment. In another case (which is between Helo and Athena when they are in their room, this is the episode I can't remember which), cylons on Caprica *feed Athena information* about Boomer so she can infiltrate among the crew. Here is another link to support that: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_Eight_(Battlestar_Galactica)#Typical_Eight_traits)

Answer (score 1):

In The Plan it is clearly shown that Boomer operates in "spy mode" where she actually believes she is a human and "normal mode" where she knows she is a Cylon and performs her mission to sabotage Galactica etc.

During the time when she is in normal mode she could have downloaded a copy of her mindstate so that other 8s can access it or even written an email or something. There could easily have been time after she was assigned to Galactica but before the Cylons attacked where she could have downloaded the Starbuck memory mentioned in the question. Note that downloading an update is never shown in the show and actually in The Plan the Cylons must self-euthanise themselves in order to get the fleet co-ordinates back to their side rather than use this technique.

I think in the series there are several times where the Cylons claim that they cannot instantaneously communicate their thoughts to other Cylons, however, it seems that there are probably other mechanisms to do so. For example, the hybrid on the rebel Basestar knows that D'Ana has been unboxed even though they are at least 1 jump away from the Resurrection Hub; and after Athena shoots rebel leader Natalie in "Guess What's Coming to Dinner" the hybrid on the rebel Basestar knows that a 6 has died. Another example is where Boomer shares projections with Tyrol and Hera; we don't know how much time elapsed during the sharing but it's possible it was faster than real time.

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: @meat-trademark Citation to what ? You know that "The Plan" is the straight-to-DVD sequel movie, right ?

Comment: Yes I do. But it doesn't really answer the question. Your answer seems to be based on theories alone. Plus, the parts about the hybrid don't help since she's a (possibly) singular being. No compatibility analogy has any canon weight, As far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember this specifically, but the [Battlestar Galactica Wiki](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Sharon_Agathon) says the following:

> Sharon is able to impersonate Lieutenant Valerii convincingly, since
>   she has accessed Valerii's memories at least up until the point of
>   Helo being left behind on Caprica (TRS: "Flesh and Bone", "Scattered",
>   "Home, Part II", "Flight of the Phoenix", "Scar").

Comment: It seems they made a big deal of dying being the main way to access memories. You reference a wiki, but did the **show** ever address this possible inconsistency?

Comment: Right, but the quote specifically says "accessed", not "copied when resurrected". This was probably some [early installment weirdness](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EarlyInstallmentWeirdness) (careful!).

Comment: I am asking if the **series** ever addressed this. I appreciate your help (especially with that initial edit), but that quote and the wiki isn't helping. I don't remember the Cylons being able to just access memories. This may be a plot  inconsistency. Then again, maybe not. Maybe someone else remembers the show talking about this.

Comment: @MeatTrademark There was that thing with the Final Five

Comment: @MeatTrademark The Final Five were able to access each other's memories by coming into contact with each other/that fluid. Something of the sort must have happened to Boomer. The episode you reference is so early in the series, so they probably didn't have an explanation yet beyond "they are robots, so their memories can be accessed some way or another"

Comment: As I'm now rewatching the series *again*, maybe I'll find the answer, maybe not..

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is not fully answered in the series. The only thing that makes sense to me is that when the Galactica Boomer landed on the Cylon ship that contained all the other #8 models and planted the nuke, it was implied that she was then "activated." At that point the cylons were able to download her memories.

Otherwise, I am not sure there is any explanation. It doesn't add up that all cylon copies are instantly aware of the experiences of all the others. The story definitely implies that either a regeneration process, after death (for which a cylon could be "out of range" to even come back, or a "hive mind" telepathic ability when in proximity to each other.

Therefore, it is a reasonable deduction that there was a telepathic hive mind download of Sharon when she first met all the other copies of her aboard the Cylon ship.